# Communication between objects of different class c++

Tags: c++

How could I keep an object valid in a different class? Here is an example below.
This code would give as a result on the screen:

```
2
2
```

What I want is to give me this:

```
2
3
```

In other words, I desire object `Bita` (or even the whole class `two`) to acknowledge object `Alpha` and not create a new object.
Is there a way to include the object Alpha to object Bita ? Please be simple because I am a beginner.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class one
{
    int a, b;
public:
    one() { a = 2; }
    int func()
    {
        return a;
    }
    void func2()
    {
        a = 3;
    }
};

class two
{
    int z, b;
public:
    void test();
};

void two::test()
{
    one Alpha;
    cout << Alpha.func() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    one Alpha;
    cout << Alpha.func() << '\n';
    Alpha.func2();
    two Bita;
    Bita.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. This seems like some terrible code smell (i. e. a design error). You might well be a victim of the XY problem. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: It sounds like you want `a` to be declared `static`, but your question really isn't clear. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to pass the object by reference you method `two::test` like this

```
class two
{
    int z, b;
public:
    void test(one& a);
};

void two::test(one& a)
{
    cout << a.func() << '\n';
}
```

And then call it in `main`

```
Bita.test(Alpha);
```

So the full code will be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class one {
    int a, b;

public:
    one() { a = 2; }
    int func() { return a; }
    void func2() { a = 3; }
};

class two {
    int z, b;

public:
    void test(one&);
};

void two::test(one& a) {
    cout << a.func() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    one Alpha;
    cout << Alpha.func() << '\n';
    Alpha.func2();
    two Bita;
    Bita.test(Alpha);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: still the result on screen remains :
2
2

Comment: Oh yes . its 2 3 :). thanks and sorry.
So what you do is passing by reference the object one..nice!
Is there another way ,such as just including the object Alpha in the object Bita? for example,using the command #include ?

Comment: If you just want to use only one instance of `one` in all your code, just use a `static` attributes and methods for this.

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of an object has its own values for its member variables. So when you declare two Bita, and call Bita.test(), test() creates its own object of class Alpha inside of it, with its own value, which is still at 2, prints that, and then that Alpha object goes out of scope and is removed from the stack as test() completes.

What you say you have in mind to do here is to have class one have what is called a static member variable. Add the keyword static:

```
static int a;
```

And then a will behave as you intend.

One explanation of this is here: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/